# Indicating a user default value - flex

Tags: flex3, user-interface, settings, default

This was just what I was thinking for this solution and I would like to know if there's a better approach I could take?

I'm creating a simple desktop contacts application.

Users have the ability to enter in peoples contact information. I've add a combo box containing city name. The user has the ability to add city to this list and then when entering in a new contact they are able to just select the city form the drop down.

Now I'm trying to add a default city feature so if someone is constantly adding contacts from the same city when they add a new contact the combo box would show the default city automatically. In the settings mode user can view the all cities via a datagrid.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I was think I could add a default_city field to the database when user selects a city and indicates it as the desired default city it would add the info to the database. Then i could just run a separate query to input the default city into the combo box's prompt.

I know I could indicate the default city by just adding another column to the dg but I was wondering if there's a way to indicate it as being the default with a icon, or bold text instead?

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use item renderers to display custom info in your data grid. There's a good tutorial here:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-using-item-renderers